# Magnify image based on rectangle points selected on image

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a code in python and I came across a figure in a report that I would like to replicate.
[image: replicate]

Basically I would like to create a 'bounding' box onto the original image, and then subsequently crop and display the part of the image that has the bounding box on it. (basically to 'magnify' that section)

I've been googling but I can't seem to find the correct function to use so that I can achieve this. Currently, opencv is used to read my image, but if there is a function in matplotlib that does this, then you can suggest that too.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In opencv c++ api you can use cv::Rect to define the region and submat = mat(cv::Rect) to create a sumbimage. Followed by cv::resize if necessary. Probably numpy in opencv python has something similar to create/crop subimages.

Comment: If you know the top left corner and bottom right corner of the rectangle, then you can both draw it and crop it. You draw using cv2.rectangle() and your crop using Numpy as image[y:y+h, x:x+w], where h=(y2-y1) and w=(x2-x1) top-left=x1,y1 and bottom-right=x2,y2